# How relevant is my SO score/badges in getting applying for a job on SO careers?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

If I apply for a job via SO careers, obviously I know that they will review my SO points and badges (right?)

Stating the obvious or perhaps my misconception:

Do they say, this guy has like 100 k reputation and 10 gold badges, lets hire him!

Or is it like, this guy has a *decent* score, lets look at his resume and get him a interview?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. No. Maybe.

No one knows for sure.

There are some stories where someone was discovered because of their SO profile.

A good SO track record can also show off your technical abilities, much better than some buzzwords on a resume.

However, there's also going to be a lot of employers who don't care, or even view a high SO score as a negative (because they could fear that the candidate will waste a lot of company time answering strangers' questions and not doing their job).

It'll depend.

See also: [Will high reputation in Stack Overflow help to get a good job?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/20407/will-high-reputation-in-stack-overflow-help-to-get-a-good-job) Where the top answer is "no" and [Does having a high “rep” on StackOverflow help you get a job? What other community sites do?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/4180/does-having-a-high-rep-on-stackoverflow-help-you-get-a-job-what-other-communi)

Answer (score 1):

I have talked to employers before who have mentioned in the interview "wow, I've never seen someone with such a high reputation on SO" (clearly they haven't spent much time on it, as there are many with higher than mine). So, it has definitely led to interest from prospective employers. Not necessarily something that will lead to them saying "let's hire him", but it is something that can distinguish your resume from the rest of the pile, and be able to get a callback for an in-person interview.